# how to share an ssh port as a rendez vous point and access it?

Tags: onion-services, ssh

I have a Linux computer with a standard SSH server running on it.  There is a public key configure on it (the only login method allowed).

I have a windows computer with the associated private key.  When I am on the same network, I can ssh be the two authenticating with public key.

I would like to run something on the Linux that create an hidden point and redirect the traffic to the SSH port, and the opposite on the windows box.

Is that doable?

If yes, what would you recommend?

Please assume that the machine have standard installation without tor related software running already.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So if I understand you correctly you want to run a hidden SSH service on your GNU/Linux machine and want to use Windows to access it.

First you have to configure a hidden service. Below I assume that your SSH daemon is already configured and running. Furthermore Tor should be installed. So open your `torrc` and add:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/myssh/
HiddenServicePort 22 127.0.0.1:22
```

After you restarted Tor look inside the `HiddenServiceDir`, which is `/var/lib/tor/myssh/` in the above case. You'll find a file `hostname` inside. This contains the name of your hidden service. The Tor website has a page about [configuring hidden services](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-hidden-service.html.en). This also might help.

On the Windows side you'll have to configure [Putty](http://www.putty.org/) to work with Tor:
[image: proxy settings]
So set *Proxy type* to SOCKS5 and *Proxy hostname* and *Port* to `localhost` and `9050`. When you start a new session with the onion URL of your hidden service Tor is used and will connect to your GNU/Linux machine.

Comment: I think your answer assume that some package you don't mention are already installed on both machine.  Can you detail what are your expectation.  I am really skeptical that this will work with standard machines.

Comment: @GuillaumeCoté Besides Putty on Windows you don't need any extra software. I changed my answer a bit.